# Stopwatch restarts each time a new component is added. ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

Brief obligatory 'Im new and completely lost, please take pity'.

I have this react component which iterates through the openOrders array, and invokes the SingleOpenOrder for each order. The SingleOpenOrder component displays some details and starts a stopwatch for the time when the order was placed.

My issue is that each times a new order is added, all the timers get reset. I know there is probably a simple solution, but for the life of me I cant figure it out.

I played around a lot and learned a good bit about state, rerenders etc; but at this stage I am going in circles and thus getting nowhere.Please help.
PS i stripped out the code which I dont think is nescessary.

```
import React, from "react";
import { menuContext } from "./MenuContext";
import SingleOpenOrder from "./SingleOpenOrder";

export default function OpenOrders() {
  const { openOrders } = useContext(menuContext);

  return (
    <div>
      {openOrders &&
        openOrders.map((order) => {
          return <SingleOpenOrder key={order.orderId} order={order} />;
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import { useStopwatch } from "react-timer-hook";
import React, { useContext } from "react";

function Stopwatch() {

//useStopwatch - npm package react-timer-hook
  const { seconds, minutes } = useStopwatch({ autoStart: true });

  return (
    <div >
      {minutes}:{seconds}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function SingleOpenOrder({ order }: { order: OrderDetails }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Stopwatch />
      <div>
        {order.orderItemDetails.map((item) => {
            return (
              <div  key={item.itemId}>
                {item.name}
              </div>
            )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I experimented with useRef in an attempt to persist state between renders.

useEffect to only start the stopwatch when the component mounts.

React.memo to try and memoize the component.

The useStopwatch hook takes an 'offsetTimestamp' Date object.

I tried creating a useref with the time the order was placed, and subtracting the current time, to offset the stopwatch start time.

Following on from Rango's comment, I have spent all day experimenting with and editing my code. I believe Rango is on to something, in that the array is being mutated somehow, which is causing the problem.

I useImmer for state in menuContext

```
  const [openOrders, setOpenOrders] = useImmer([] as OrderDetails[]);
```

And update with a new order like this

```
 // Add the order to an array of open Orders
 setOpenOrders((cur) => [orderDetails, ...cur]);
```

I think this should be ok?

This is my first real bug. I have been trying to fix it for a few days and I think im slowly losing my mind. Does that mean im a coder yet?

https://github.com/Fishamble/kitchenpos
The full code is here if anyone would be kind enough to have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Ensure that `orderId` stays the same for corresponding orders when the array mutated by adding new order. In [my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-fast-e1n3mp?file=/src/App.js) timers work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked and orderId is consistent. I am examining your sandbox and will attempt to recreate my issue. Regards, JP.